# align table cell (td) content in bulma

Tags: html-table, alignment, bulma

Bulma has very nice table layout, however I'm struggling to find how to horizontally align table data cell (`<td></td>`) content.

Simply adding

```
<td align='center'>in the middle</td>
```

Does not work.

Suggestions?

Comment: It depends of the data inside your `<td></td>`, but you can maybe use `class="has-text-centered"`, it will add a `text-align: center !important;` property and center the content. Else a simple `margin: 0 auto;` or regular center techniques can do the work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the Bulma [typography helpers](https://bulma.io/documentation/helpers/typography-helpers/#alignment) to align text in table cells (and otherwise).

In this instance `<td class="has-text-centered">` is probably what you are after.

Note there are also `has-text-right`, `has-text-left`, etc.

Comment: You can also add the class on the <table> itself if you want text in all cells in the table to be centred.